# Guardar id de windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho uma aplicação cuja autenticação é via login do windows. Com essa classe eu pego o login do usuário:

```
public static class UserDetails
{
    public static string GetLogin(string userName)
    {
        string login = userName.Substring(userName.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);

        return login;
    }
```

Nesse controle eu pego o usuário logado e através da view correspondente carrego todas as informações do usário assim que ele entra no programa.

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var login = UserDetails.GetLogin(User.Identity.Name);
        var perfil = db.Perfis.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == login);
        if (perfil == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.Id = perfil.Id;
        return View(perfil);
    }
```

Bom, eu tenho uma view cujo esse usuário logado cadastra informações referentes a ele próprio como tarefas que ele realizou e data. Porém, do modo como está o sistema, na tela de cadastro de tarefas o usuário precisa selecionar num dropdownlist o número do seu 'Login' que é a chave estrangeira da minha tabela Perfil para atribuir a ele as informações que está cadastrando no banco.
Como eu faço para guardar essa PK_Login para que o usuário não tenha que selecionar o login toda vez que for inserir uma informação já que automaticamente quando ele entra no sistema o sistema já reconhece pela autenticação do windows?
Já pesquisei as opções de cookie e session mas preferia uma outra maneira, uma forma de nessa mesma tela de inclusão de tarefas, ao invés de aparecer um dropdownlist com todos os logins para o usuário selecionar o dele, aparecer só o dele, ou melhor ainda, pegar o dele mas esconder da tela e só apontar para o banco.

Minha view onde quero esconder o Perfil.Login

```
 <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tarefa)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tarefa, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tarefa)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Inicio)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Inicio, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Inicio)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Conclusão)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Conclusão, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Conclusão)
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Perfil)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Login, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login)
        </div>

    </div>
```

Caso a única ou melhor opção seja criar um cookie ou session, qual a forma mais simples de criar?

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria assim:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Perfil)
        @ViewBag.Id
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Login)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login)
    </div>
```

Ou então nem escreveria o `Hidden`, já que você usa uma classe estática para pegar o login do usuário logado. Essa informação nem precisa aparecer na View.

---

**EDIT**

Eu não sei como é a sua `Action`, mas imagino que seja algo como o código abaixo, em que vou colocar o que você precisa pra salvar corretamente:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Modelo modelo)
{
    var login = UserDetails.GetLogin(User.Identity.Name);
    var perfil = db.Perfis.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == login);
    modelo.Perfil = perfil;

    if (ModelState.IsValid())
    {
        db.Modelos.Add(modelo);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Modelo");
    }

    // Carregue aqui as ViewBags

    return View(perfil);
}
```

Comment: Deu não. Deu o mesmo erro que as outras coisas que eu havia tentado " A instrução Insert conflitou com a restrição da FK... "

Comment: Ah, então o ponto é que você está tendo um erro com a FK na hora de inserir. É isso?

Comment: Isso. Eu só estou conseguindo inserir o login, que é minha FK, manualmente. Quero que seja inserido a fk sem que o usuário tenha que digitá-la.

Comment: Boa! Consegui! Obrigado pela ajuda!